# How can I plot a sine wave with a flat top and dotted part of it?

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm looking for a way to plot the waveform with a flat top and dotted line of a sine as in the second or third curves. 
How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

```
gap = 1/4;

pw0 = Piecewise[{{ 2/3 Sin[ x], 0 <= x <= 2 π}}, Undefined];

pw1 = Piecewise[{{gap + Sin[ x - π/2], 2 π + π/2 <= x <= 4 π + π /2},
    {-gap + Sin[ x - π], 5 π <= x <= 7 π}}, Undefined];
```

Text, line and arrow primitives to annotate the plot:

```
annotations = {Text[Style["0", 14], Offset[{-15, 0}, {0, 0}], {1, 0}],
   Text[Style["+Vcc", 14], Offset[{-10, 10}, {0, 1}], {1, 0}],
   Text[Style["-Vcc", 14], Offset[{-10, -10}, {0, -1}], {1, 0}],
   Text[Style["Input\nSignal", 14], Offset[{0, -10}, {π/2, 0}], {0, 1}],
   Text[Style["ωt", 14], Offset[{-15, 15}, {2 π, 0}], {1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["Bias level\nto High", 14], Offset[{0, 5}, {4 π, gap}], {0, -1}],
   Text[Style["Bias level\nto Low", 14], Offset[{0, -5}, {5 π + π/2, -gap}], {0, 1}],
   Text[Style["Positive\nHalf Clipped", 14], 
      Offset[{-10, 2}, {3 π + π/2, 1}], {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style["Negative\nHalf Clipped", 14], Offset[{10, -2}, {6 π, -1}], {1, 1}],
   Text[Style["Distorted Output\nSignal", 14], {6 π, 2/3}, {-1, 0}],
   Text[Style["0v", 14], {7 π, 0}, {1, -1}],
   Gray, Arrowheads[.03], 
   Arrow[{Offset[{-30, 10}, {2 π, 0}], Offset[{10, 10}, {2 π, 0}]}],
   Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}], Arrow[{{4 π, 0}, {4 π, gap}}],
   Arrow[{{5 π + π/2, 0}, {5 π + π/2, -gap}}],
   Line[{Offset[{-20, 0}, {2 π + π/2, gap}], Offset[{20, 0}, {4 π + π/2, gap}]}],
   Line[{Offset[{-20, 0}, {5 π, -gap}], Offset[{20, 0}, {7 π, -gap}]}]};
```

Use `annotations` as `Epilog` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[{pw0, pw1, Clip[pw1, {-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 7 π + π/2},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5]],
   Directive[Gray, Dashed],
   Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5], RGBColor[0.2, 0.4, 0.2]]},
 GridLines -> {None, {-1, 1}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashing[Large]],
 ImageSize -> 700,
 Ticks -> False,
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[Large], Automatic},
 Epilog -> annotations, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 10}, {10, 10}}]
```

> picture above

Comment: really impressive! Other people also gave nice answers which is simple too.

Answer (score 9):

```
Plot[{#, Clip[#, {-0.8, 0.8}]}
   , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
   , PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Gray}, {Opacity[1], Thick, Darker@Cyan}}
   ] &@Sin[x]
```

[image]

---

You can change opacity to make the other dotted waveform more visible.

---

**EDIT-1**

The `Clip` function has a third argument that makes it more versatile for plotting waveforms for clipping and clamping circuits. You can choose another function during clipped phases. As a simpler demonstration:

```
Plot[{#, Clip[#, {-0.8, 0.8}, {-0.3, 0.5}]}
   , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
   , Exclusions -> None
   , PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Gray}, {Opacity[1], Thick, Darker@Cyan}}
   ] &@Sin[x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

```
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {{-.8, .8}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  MeshShading -> {Dotted, 
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Darker@Cyan]}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Tiny], Blue]] /. {Dotted, 
   Line[a_]} :> {{Dotted, Line[a]}, {Red, Line[{First[a], Last[a]}]}}
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Show[Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-.8, .8}}, 
  ClippingStyle -> {Red, Brown}, PlotStyle -> Green], 
 Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Abs@y > .8], 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dotted}], PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 6):

Some ideas

```
Show[
 Plot[Min[Sin[x], 0.8], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, ArcSin[0.8], Pi - ArcSin[0.8]}, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Couldn't you repeat the trick in the first line? Plot `Min[Sin[x], 0.8]` with `Thick` and `Max[Sin[x], 0.8]` with `Dashed`. Then you could do everything in one Plot call if you want

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion  With `Plot[{Min[Sin[x], 0.8], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]` I see the dashes are visible throughout the plot, so the second plot in my answer only plots dashes where they should be seen.